# Displaystyle and left-alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, displaystyle

```
\newcommand{\mbi}[1]{\textbf{\emph{#1}}}
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{large}
\displaystyle
\begin{equation}
{\mbi s} = {\mbi P}{\mbi d}, {\qquad{(2)}}\nonumber
\end{equation}
\end{large}
\end{document}
```

I'm using displaystyle to get the image without the white space. But this invariably produces errors and warnings. When I don't use it, there are no errors, but then this produces extra white space on the left. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is also possible to modify this border for left/right and top/bottom border using `border={<l/r> <t/b>}` or for each border specifically using `border={<l> <r> <b> <t>}`. These options are described in the [`standalone` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf) (section **2.2 Class options**, p 6).

Comment: why not omit the `\begin{equation} ...\nonumber\end{equation}` and just surround the math with single `$` signs?  the `\displaystyle` should take care of the choice of shapes and limit styles.

Comment: The instructions `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, and `\scriptscriptstyle` should *only* be use in math mode. Currently, you issue `\displaystyle` outside of math mode. Incidentally, upon entering an `equation` environment LaTeX is automatically in `\displaystyle` math mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the content in a `varwidth` environment, and use `\Large` to obtain larger text:

[image]

As mentioned in the comments `\displaystyle` should be used in math mode, So if you were using inline math `$ ... $`, the you could add `\displaystyle` as follows:

```
$\displaystyle {\mbi s} = {\mbi P}{\mbi d}, {\qquad{(2)}}\nonumber$
```

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\newcommand{\mbi}[1]{\textbf{\emph{#1}}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\Large
\begin{equation}
{\mbi s} = {\mbi P}{\mbi d}, {\qquad{(2)}}\nonumber
\end{equation}
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The "correct" way to write the document is, in my opinion,

```
\documentclass[border=0 0 0 1]{standalone}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\large
$\displaystyle
\bm{s} = \bm{P}\bm{d},\qquad{(2)}
$
\end{document}
```

Notice how I get the boldface math italic letters. The `\displaystyle` is reduntant, in this case, but it's needed in case you have "big operators" such as `\sum`. Here's the result

[image]